# How to install Pygame on Sublime Text on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sublimetext3, importerror

I've been using python on my MacBook Pro (2018) for a couple months and it seems to be overheating like crazy. but only when I'm using IDLE. So I decided to switch to Sublime Text as an alternative.

Does anyone know how to get PyGame to work on sublime text on macOS?

I'm getting an error saying:

```
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

even thought I do have PyGame installed correctly as I have been using it on python's IDLE. I've even deleted and reinstalled PyGame but still no hope.

Any tips??

Comment: How did you install `pygame`? With `pip install pygame` or with another command?

Comment: By default Sublime runs `python` to execute Python scripts, so if you're for example using Python 3, then that would be installed as `python3` and thus Sublime is using the wrong version to run your program.

Comment: @NinoFiliu yeah I used the pip install Pygame command

Comment: pip either install packages for Python3 or Python2.7 or both. Check that you installed the package with the right version.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like Python does not know that Pygame is installed. Therefore, you have to reference it. Using Package Control that comes with Sublime Text 3 seems like the best idea for you. Here's a quick guide -

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-will-not-import-pygame/12545